# Gallery View of a PowerPivot Gallery not working

Tags: publishing-page, view, powerpivot

I am using SharePoint Server 2013. I have a Power Pivot Gallery with several Power Pivot Excel files and Power View files. Besides **All Documents** view, the Power Pivot Gallery has several beautiful views such as **Gallery**, **Theater** and **Carousel** which are available out of the box. In the original Power Pivot Gallery library all these views are working perfectly.

But when I insert this Power Pivot Gallery as a **web part** or **app part** in another SharePoint **page**, only the **All Documents** view work where as Gallery, Theater and Carousel views does not work. Though there is an option to select the view for that web part, it always renders as **All Documents** view.

I tested the same thing with **Image** library. Its thumbnail view works perfectly when this Image library is added as app part in another SharePoint page.

Help please.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a fairly old post but I had the same issue and similarly could not find a resolution to the problem so decided to use the following workaround.

I have a site collection with standard landing page and 2 sub sites.

In a sub site - Create your power pivot gallery and add content to test

1. Open the Power Pivot gallery
2. Set library view to carousel or your preferred view.
3. Select Modify view and set as default view for the library

On the main site

1. In the main site select settings->Navigation
2. Add a link to global navigation and insert the url to the library you created previously
3. Hide the link to the existing sub site

The work around is clunky because you cannot add additional content however I wanted impress with the visual effect of the gallery.

Answer (score 0):

are you using the pageviewer webpart, did you select the all items view? try to set the Gallery view as default.
check these blogs for more detial:
http://plexhosted.com/billing/knowledgebase/296/How-to-show-a-Power-View-report-at-the-SharePoint-page-Page-Viewer-Web-Part.html

Comment: Hi Waqas Sarwar. Thanks for your input. I already tried all the options available, that are Gallery, Theater and Carousel. None of these views worked on Page Viewer web part. They all rendered as All Documents view.

And the link that you posted shows about including a Power View Report on a Page Viewer web part and not the Power Pivot Gallery.